# How to generate/delete number suffix that follows the number sequence? PHP

Tags: php

I am working on widget area ( sidebars )  generator that automatically adds a number suffix to the widget area name.

Desired sidebars names output when created should be

```
custom_sidebar_area1
custom_sidebar_area2
custom_sidebar_area3
...
```

If custom_sidebar_area2  is deleted

```
custom_sidebar_area1
custom_sidebar_area3
```

the next created sidebar should be again

```
custom_sidebar_area2
```

the one after is than  custom_sidebar_area4

**The issue:**

This snippet currently works for creation and is saved in an array of areas and suffix index to keep track for the next number,

```
$custom_sidebars = get_theme_mod( 'custom_sidebars' );
$new_sidebar_name = $_POST['newSidebarName'];
$suffix = $custom_sidebars ? intval( $custom_sidebars['suffix'] ) + 1 : 1;

$custom_sidebars['areas']['custom_sidebar_area' . $suffix] = $new_sidebar_name ;
$custom_sidebars['suffix'] = $suffix;
```

when saved this is the array output

```
array
(
    [areas] => array
    (
        [custom_sidebar_area5] => 'Title'
        [custom_sidebar_area6] => 'New widget area'
    )
    [suffix] => 6
)
```

now this works perfect for creation , but I need the deletion of the sidebar to 
follow the order and update the suffix accordingly.

If I used something like this

```
    $old_sidebar_name = $_POST['oldSidebarName'];
    $custom_sidebars = get_theme_mod( 'custom_sidebars' );
    $suffix = $custom_sidebars ? intval( $custom_sidebars['suffix'] ) - 1 : 1;

    unset( $custom_sidebars['areas'][$old_sidebar_name] );

    $custom_sidebars['suffix'] = $suffix;
```

the order works until you start skipping the deletion and instead deleting last in order you delete the number 2. Than the next created sidebar can override the existing one.

If I dont use the suffix change when deleting , the suffix will always increase , and user that has previously deleted ALL of the created sidebars (let say there was 5 ), on new sidebar creation will have

```
custom_sidebar_area6
```

instead

```
custom_sidebar_area1
```

What would be best approach to get out of this ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about having a (numbered) array of sidebars? like `sidebars[1]` , `sidebars[5]` , ... and only rename them for displaying?

Comment: @Burki post a suggestion if you see the issue please. I think I see what you saying , cant do that since the names are used by admin in themes. thus the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that scans the current array to determine an available suffix.

Here is the little test I setup that works as expected:

```
$a = array('a1'=>1, 'a2'=>2, 'a3'=>4);
function getSuffix($a){
    for($i=1; $i<=count($a)+1; $i++ ){
        if( ! array_key_exists("a$i", $a) ){
            return $i;    
        }    
    }
}
```

Then this line:

```
 $suffix = $custom_sidebars ? intval( $custom_sidebars['suffix'] ) - 1 : 1;
```

can become:

```
$suffix = $custom_sidebars ? getSuffix($custom_sidebars['area']) : 1;
```